# Full-Screen, Transparent App & Main Menu Interaction

Tags: cocoa, menu, fullscreen, objective-c-2.0

I'm making an app that covers the screen, so I have a window covering the screen completely, with its level higher than the main menu.

So I draw over the main menu, but I want the main menu to be accessible, still.

How would I do so?

Comment: Can't you just move down the window under the menu level but still above other windows?

Comment: I want to draw over the main menu too. But thanks! Thought of tracking click coordinates and if it's on the main-menu pass it through - but maybe others have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is probably best (and also MAS acceptable) to force your app to run in full-screen mode. That way the menubar will still display if the user hovers in its area but you get the benefit of using the entire screen.